Why is the first word of the abstract word does not displayed Bolded?
I am writing an abstract in LaTeX, and I want to bold the first phrase of the abstract, specifically "Background:". However, only the first-word "Background" is not bolded and appears in regular font, while "Objective:" is bolded. Here is the code I am using:
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\begin{document}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
\begin{abstract}
\textbf{Background:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. \hfill \break
\textbf{Objective:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{abstract}
\section{Section}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{document}

How to format the first word in the abstract to be bolded?
Output


Please show a complete example.

..."complete" meaning a full, compilable code that demonstrates the problem. We must know the document class and any packages used that may affect the result. Please do not include packages and commands that do not affect the result.

unrelated to the font but why do you have  \hfill \break ? neither should appear in the document, just in code definitions (and it's helpful if you post here with a reasonable line length so that you don't have to scroll the example to see ends of lines)

The picture is very blurry, so I can’t really see which parts are bold an which are not. Better show a MWE.

Welcome to TeX.SE! I can't compile your MWE, but try with the hack {}\textbf{Background:}.

Just provide \protect command after \begin{abstract} will fix the issue, but not sure if this is the correct method, and the MWE is:
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\begin{document}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
\begin{abstract}
\protect\textbf{Background:} Lorem...
....
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
...
\end{document}


You have provided no code but my guess is that you are using a document class that expects \abstract as a command taking the text as argument, rather than an environment. In such a case the fragment shown would have \textbf on its own as the abstract then the rest of the text would be typeset.

\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand\abstract[1]{%
  \parindent=0pt
  \par\hrule \smallskip ABSTRACT\par #1 \hrule\smallskip }

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
  \textbf{Background:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
  dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
  exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat. \hfill \break
  \textbf{Objective:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
  ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
  nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
  consequat.
\end{abstract}


\end{document}


The cas-dc class is written in a “peculiar” way.
You can add \relax after \begin{abstract}; the problem is that if the first token is a control sequence, it gets lost.
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}\relax
\textbf{Background:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat.

\textbf{Objective:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\end{document}


A more effective cure would be to fix the definition of abstract.
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentEnvironment { abstract } { o }
{
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 } { }
   { \tl_gset:Nn \abstracttitle { #1 } }
  \verbatimwrite{\jobname.abs}\relax
}
{ \endverbatimwrite }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\textbf{Background:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat.

\textbf{Objective:} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore 
et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud 
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat.
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut 
enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

\end{document}

If you want no indentation of the second paragraph, use
\noindent\textbf{Objective:}

and not \hfill\break. Paragraphs should always be separated by a blank line.
